# android programmatically access favorite contacts

Tags: android

I'm getting the device contacts with the following:

```
    Cursor c = getBaseContext()
            .getContentResolver()
            .query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                    null, null);
```

How would I go about getting contacts marked as favorites?  Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Some version of the Contacts APP use this 'favorites' group to manager contacts, some don't, so it is not possible.

Comment: is there a programmatic way to determine at run time if the Contacts APP supports favorites?